# Setting background image not showing on child divs

Tags: html, css, position, background-image, styling

About Us and Contact Us are my two sections. The contact us section's background property is working well. However, I now want to add a background picture to both divs' parent wrappers. Therefore, the background image may be seen above both divs. I am unable to identify the issue that is preventing me from displaying the background image.

index.html:

```
 <div class="aboutus-contact-us-wrapper" >
    <div class="about-us-section">
     // content here
    </div>

    <div class="contact-us">
    // content here
    </div>

   </div>
```

style.css:

```
.aboutus-contact-us-wrapper {

  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('./images/ourboardvector.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: contain;

}

.contact-us {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #181f2b;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

.about-us-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  font-family: 'Lato' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set `z-index` of both child divs to `-1`.**

> Z Index ( `z-index` ) is a CSS property that defines the order of overlapping HTML elements. Elements with a higher index will be placed on top of elements with a lower index. Note: Z index only works on positioned elements ( `position:absolute` , `position:relative` , or `position:fixed` )

```css
.aboutus-contact-us-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('./images/ourboardvector.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: contain;
}

.contact-us {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #181f2b;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.about-us-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  font-family: 'Lato' !important;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutus-contact-us-wrapper">
  <div class="about-us-section">
    // content here
  </div>

  <div class="contact-us">
    // content here
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It works by setting the z-index : -1.  Thanks man!!

Comment: I'd like to know why it didn't appear. As you can see, I skipped the +1 z-index. So why wasn't it showing?

Comment: Because if a positioned element has a z-index of X, then all of its children will also be stuck with a z-value of X. So applying parent div z-index: +1 means you are also applying child divs with z-index: +1 also.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation. Now, the issue is in about-us section anchor tag is not working.what should i do now?. I want the bg and other tags working too.

Comment: I applied the Z-index 2 to parent and 1 to childs. but now, the bg is not showing .

Comment: I also noticed it now. Actually, this is a limitation of the z-index with positioned elements in DOM. The workaround to this is to move the child divs out of parent div and into the main stacking context of the page. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I got it. But how can i move child divs into main stacking context. i would be thankful to you for this favor

Comment: Sure! You can lookup into this reference to learn more:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249494/discussion-between-sohaib-and-s-m-samnoon-abrar).